# how to call a php file from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I am very new to JavaScript, looking for some help. I have a form, shown below. When the user gives input and clicks submit, I want to call a php file (shown below also) to be invoked and return a hello. Here is the code I have tried, though it is not working as intended.

```
 <html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="name-typed" type="text"  />
<input id="name-submit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="post()"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
<script>
function post() {
 var hname = $('input#name-typed').val();
 $.post('dat.php',{name: hname},function(data) {
$('div#result').html(data);
});
  }
</script>
</html>
```

The PHP file dat.php looks like this:
    `<?php echo "hello";?>`

As in my first paragraph, can anyone suggest any changes I should make?

Comment: you need to prevent form to be submited. So in your case, use as input type `button`

Comment: My humble opinion, use of the `onclick` attribute is unnecessary. Please refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

you can change dat.php to say:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Hello ".$name;

?>
```

And then your html file would be:

Notice that the button type is changed to a normal button so that it just execute the function rather than submitting the form.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="name-typed" type="text"  />
<button type="button" onclick="post()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
<script>
function post() {
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "dat.php",
        data: { name: $('#name-typed').val()
             },
        success: function(response) {

                $('#result').html(response);
       }
    });
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks you very much   both the files seem to be working fine individually but when i give some input and run this is how it appears http://localhost:82/hello/index.php? and nothing changes

Comment: check my most recent edit just so you have the correct `<button>`.  And you are welcome

Comment: excellent, please accept the answer, and welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test but something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
post()
return false;//block the reload of the page
})
```

In fact I think you just forget the return false. remvove the onclick if you use my answer

Comment: Better example, because of the use of unobtrusive javascript, in my opinion.